# Result of function is undefined instead of object

Tags: javascript

When I call for the below function *maxSubArraySum* it does not return with the object *arrSlice* which I expect to do so.  Instead when I run the code in chrome developer tools, I get undefined as the result.

```js
function maxSubArraySum(array, count) {
  var slicePoint1;
  var slicePoint2 = count;
  var arrSlice = {};
  var pH;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      slicePoint1 = i;
      pH = array.slice(slicePoint1, slicePoint2);
      if(pH.length<count){
       return;
      }
      arrSlice[i] = pH;
      slicePoint2 += 1;
     
  }//End of loop

  console.log(arrSlice);
  return arrSlice;
}

maxSubArraySum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4);
```

Comment: `return;` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The moment you are using some return, doesn't kick you out of the for scope - It returns nothing and finishes the function. So your return arrSlice will never reach if your (pH.length < count) gets called.

Comment: i would recommend to have only one return. it makes things easy.

Comment: Maybe instead of `return;` you need to break loop with `break` or continue to other element with `continue;`?

Comment: why not first check the type of variable you are returning? this way you might know why it is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this condition

```
if(pH.length<count){
        return;
      }
```

The empty return statement returns undefined, i pasted debug code below,please elaborate your question so i can correct it

```
function maxSubArraySum(array, count) {
  var slicePoint1;
  var slicePoint2 = count;
  var arrSlice = {};
  var pH;
console.log(arguments);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    slicePoint1 = i;
      pH = array.slice(slicePoint1, slicePoint2);
      if(pH.length<count){
        console.log("dsf");return;
      }
      arrSlice[i] = pH;
      slicePoint2 += 1;

  }//End of loop

  console.log("sdf",arrSlice);
  return arrSlice;
}

maxSubArraySum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4);
```

Comment: I used two  returns, I used break instead of return. Now my code is perfect thank you.